# Listview remove particular file name

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm stuck on this part of my project
I have a listview filled up with files from a specific folder, it get all files from a folder but I need to make a filter only for 
"zw1(random numbers and letters)".txt, what am I doing wrong?

here's the code

```
   public void DataFromFolders1(string fileName = "*")
    {

        string zw1 = "zw1";
        LV1.Items.Remove($"{zw1}*.txt");

        LV1.Items.Clear();


        //zet files van een folder in de listbox als de path correct is
        //de paths kan je boven aan vinden boven InitializeComponent();

        if (dinfo.Exists)
        {
            //FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles($"{fileName}*.txt");

            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)

            {
                LV1.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Pad van niet gedaan folder niet gevonden!");
        }
    }
```

I have this method in a timer
also the parameter {fileName} is from a date picker ignore that.

Thanks in advance (;

Comment: You need to use Regex here. `Items.Remove` will remove exact match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^zw1\.txt$"); //This regex looks for the file name, 
   foreach (var item in LV1) //Check every item
      if (regex.Match(item).Success) //If item matches the regex
         LV1.Remove(item); // remove item
```

Implimentation.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private List<string> aListOfItems;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public List<string> AListOfItems
  {
     get { return aListOfItems; }
     set { aListOfItems = value; OnPropertyChanged("AListOfItems"); }
  }
  public MainWindow()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = this;
     AListOfItems = new List<string> { "item1", "item2", "item3", "zw1.txt","hey"};
     ThisIsTheRemoveCode();
  }

  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  }

  private void ThisIsTheRemoveCode()
  {
     Regex regex = new Regex(@"^zw1\.txt$");
     for (int i = 0; i < AListOfItems.Count; i++)
        if (regex.Match(AListOfItems[i]).Success)
           AListOfItems.Remove(AListOfItems[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried the code and var item in LV1 has an error.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ListView' because 'ListView' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator

Comment: I have updated my code, this should do as youve asked.